# Singular points of Legendre elliptic curve over field $k$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let k be an algebraically closed field of characteristic different from $2$.

$(1)$ Prove that the Legendre elliptic curve over k given by the equation $y^2= x(x−1)(x−λ)$ (where
$λ \in k$ is a scalar) is non-singular iff $\lambda\neq  0, 1$.

$(2)$ Find all the singular points when $λ = 0,1$

Not sure how to solve it in algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x,y)=y^2-x(x-1)(x-\lambda)$. At a singular point in the affine plane, both
$f$ and its first-order partial derivatives vanish. But
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2y$$
so at a singular point $y=0$. As $f=0$, then $x\in\{0,1,\lambda\}$.
Finally we need
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-x(x-1)-x(x-\lambda)-(x-1)(x-\lambda)$$
to vanish. Putting $x=0$, $1$ and $\lambda$ in in turn, one finds a solution
iff $\lambda\in\{0,1\}$.